# Is the adverb used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Is the adverb "instantly" used correctly in this sentence?

> At that moment both of them did not see each other's action and Tad was hit by Jim instantly.

Comment: What do you mean by "used correctly"? Do you mean its positioning? Its meaning?

Comment: I meant both ofthat.Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence as a position of the adverb instantly is correct. It means immediately and adverbs are used after verb.

But as a meaning of the adverb it might be better to use unexpectedly. 
Instantly and suddenly are also can be used in this sentence.